# Special slide down in a ListView

Tags: android, animation

I need to animate the following scenario:

[image]

I have a ListView, each cell have 3 Layouts in it:

- A **preview_layout** (blue): contains a preview of the contents of the contents_layout.
- A **contents_layout** (green): contains a long text with some buttons.
- A **wrapper_layout** (red): contains preview_layout and contents_layout.

The contents_layout is set with visibility to "**gone**", so only the preview_layout are visible in the list.

When a cell of the ListView is pressed I need to show the contents_layout with a slide down animation.

Until now I used the following solution:

In the *getView* of the ListView:

```
// Preview_layouts height
int hPreview = 70;
// Views
final View previewView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.preview);
final View contentsView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.contents);
// On previewView click
previewView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!contentsView.isShown()) { 
            // Close all the contents_layout of the ListView (menuListView)
            for (int i=0; i < menuListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = menuListView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.contents);
                if (v.isShown()) { v.startAnimation(new SlideUpAnimation(v, hPreview)); }
            }
            // Slide down the selected contents_layout (contentsView)
            contentsView.startAnimation(new SlideDownAnimation(contentsView, hPreview));
        }
    }
});
```

The SlideDownAnimation class:

```
public class SlideDownAnimation extends Animation {
    private View target;
    private LayoutParams targetResize;
    private int mFromHeight, mToHeight;
    public SlideDownAnimation( View targetToSlideDown, int fromHeight ) {
        // Show the contents_layout target
        target = targetToSlideDown;
        target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Animation property
        setDuration(500); 
        setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        // Target
        targetResize = targetToSlideDown.getLayoutParams();
        mFromHeight = fromHeight;
        mToHeight = targetResize.height - fromHeight;
        targetResize.height = 1;
    }
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        // Set the Alpha to fade in the contents_layout target
        t.setAlpha(interpolatedTime);
        // Set the height to slide down the contents_layout target
        targetResize.height = (int) (mToHeight * interpolatedTime) + mFromHeight;
        target.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

The big problem with this solution is that I cannot get the **height** of the contents_layout if it is set to **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** and the visibility is GONE, it just return "0".

Do you have any other solutions to perform the animation that I need?

Comment: if you've solved this problem can you please paste the code . I also need to do the same  thing ?

Comment: nope, i'm still looking for a solution... seems that it's not an easy task to do with Android :(

Comment: Have a look at this sample. This might help you https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/ExpandAnimationExample